# Is the category of elements an example of a fibred category?

Tags: category-theory

Given a presheaf $F: A^{op} \rightarrow Set$ from some category $A$, the category of elements constructs a functor $p: El F \rightarrow A$.

Is this an example of a fibred category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the category of elements of a presheaf on $\mathcal{A}$ is a fibred category over $\mathcal{A}$.

In fact, a Grothendieck fibration $p : \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{A}$ comes from a presheaf (of sets) if and only if the following is a pullback square of sets:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{mor} \mathcal{E} @>{\operatorname{codom}}>> \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{E} \\
@V{\operatorname{mor} p}VV @VV{\operatorname{ob} p}V \\
\operatorname{mor} \mathcal{A} @>>{\operatorname{codom}}> \operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}
\end{CD}$$
Such a Grothendieck fibration is called a **discrete fibration**.